# Takes last 20 record and show last register

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-mysql

So i have a problem and i dont know how to look for him.

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        current_user.update_on = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.add(current_user)
        db.session.commit()
    username = db.session.query(User.username,User.avatar).order_by(User.username,User.avatar).limit(20).all()
    nicks = [x[0]for x in username]
    base = 'http://localhost:5000/profil'
    urls = ['{}/{}'.format(base,n)for n in nicks]
    return render_template("index.html",user = username,urls=urls,nicks=nicks)
```

This is my code in app.py, so i want takes last 20 records from mysql, and show last records in html. Last register user will be first showed, and prelast was be second... but in html show me random Users.
My `HTML` file:

```
<a href="{{urls[0] }}"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{url_for('static',filename='upload/'+ user[0].avatar|resize('40x40'))}}" alt="{{nicks[0]}}"></a>
        <a href="{{urls[1] }}"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{url_for('static',filename='upload/'+ user[1].avatar|resize('40x40'))}}" alt="{{nicks[1]}}"></a>
        <a href="{{urls[2] }}"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{url_for('static',filename='upload/'+ user[2].avatar|resize('40x40'))}}" alt="{{nicks[2]}}"></a>
```

I dont know how repair this error, someone can help me ? or just give me a tips ? Im was start learning programming in last week

And another problem i have with  `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')` its to fast end connect, like 2min and see a error

```
DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/kamilos98'.format(config['user'], config['password'],config['host'], config['port'])
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DATABASE_URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
username = db.session.query( \
    User.username,User.avatar).order_by(User.username,User.avatar).limit(20).all()
```

Orders by user name and avatar. Change it to:

```
username = db.session.query( \
    User.username,User.avatar).order_by(User.update_on.desc(),User.username).limit(20).all()
```

to order them by the last update time instead.

Comment: Can you tell me why in order_by is User.update_on ? This column is to show when user was last seen on website

Comment: @Tshibe Then `order_by(User.created.desc(), ...)` - replace `created` with the column that holds your "registered at date xx.xx.xxxx" date.

Comment: I was do like you said on the top, and stil dont work,show me a random users

Comment: Okey, now its work, just forget about .desc() But if you can help me with  'Lost connection to MySQL server during query' its to fast end connect